# wordpress dynamic csv import

Tags: wordpress, selenium

I'm **scraping** some data periodically from the internet and write it to a csv file with a python code on a 7/24 computer. This csv file is in my dropbox folder, so I can check it whenever I want with its dropbox link.

Can I also publish it dynamically on my very simple twentytwentone themed WordPress page? I mean, I want to see the fresh data in the csv file whenever I check my webpage.

Checked WP All import, but only pro version can import csv file from URL and the cheapest pro vers. is 100 USD. It would be pointless for me to pay this price for such an amateur project.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create additional python script just to upload results one for a time via http request (just like user but with skipping UI part)?

Comment: You mean to convert the csv file to one html file and upload it via ftp to the server periodically? Sorry for noob question.

Comment: No. In browser look into network tab (f12, then network). If you use Wordpress backofice you preform a bunch of request to your Wordpress server. During the CSV upload you probably use HTTP POST method to file upload.

So If you have a file, know http method, and know some Python basics. You can create script to automatically upload csv file in 3 steps: 
1. Get CSV file;
2. Get authetication token ("login to wordpress");
3. POST csv file to the server;